# How to create an editable excel

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, closedxml

I am creating an Excel file:

```
SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filename, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook)
WorkbookPart workBookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
            workBookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

            WorksheetPart workSheetPart = workBookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            workSheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();


            Sheets sheets = workBookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

            Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
            {
                Id = workBookPart.GetIdOfPart(workSheetPart),
                SheetId = 1,
                Name = "Test Sheet"
            };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            workBookPart.Workbook.Save();
```

When I open the file it's only ReadOnly, how I can make it editable to the user?

ClosedXML is the priority, alternative way of the solution can be OpenXML

Comment: Close VS.  When VS is still open the file is readonly because VS application still has it open.

Comment: @jdweng it's closed and still when I open the file it's only ReadOnly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've provided there creates an invalid file rather that one that would be read-only. There are 2 minor issues. Firstly, there must be exactly one [`SheetData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.sheetdata(v=office.15).aspx) element under each `Worksheet` and secondly you need to call the [`Close`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpackage.close.aspx) method on the document (either directly or indirectly via a using statement).

The following code will create you a file that is editable with an explicit call to `Close`

```
SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filename, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
WorkbookPart workBookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
workBookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

WorksheetPart workSheetPart = workBookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
workSheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

//a worksheet *must* have exactly one child SheetData
workSheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());

Sheets sheets = workBookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
{
    Id = workBookPart.GetIdOfPart(workSheetPart),
    SheetId = 1,
    Name = "Test Sheet"
};
sheets.Append(sheet);

workBookPart.Workbook.Save();

//the document must be closed (and ideally disposed)
document.Close();
document.Dispose();
```

Here's the same but with the `using` statement instead:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filename, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
    WorkbookPart workBookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
    workBookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

    WorksheetPart workSheetPart = workBookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    workSheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

    //a worksheet *must* have exactly one child SheetData
    workSheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());

    Sheets sheets = workBookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

    Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
    {
        Id = workBookPart.GetIdOfPart(workSheetPart),
        SheetId = 1,
        Name = "Test Sheet"
    };
    sheets.Append(sheet);

    workBookPart.Workbook.Save();
}
```

**Edit**

Doing this in ClosedXml is much simpler. The following will produce an equivalent workbook:

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
....

var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test Sheet");
workbook.SaveAs(filename);
```

Comment: is there a way to reproduce it with closedxml? Your answer is perfect, but just the functionality which is required for the excel file is much easier to be done with closedXML, but I am encountering the same issue when using the closedxml, that the file is Read-Only. Just I want the whole project to be done with closedXML not to be mixed with OpenXML

Comment: Hi @Toni, I've updated the answer to include a ClosedXml example.